# Creating an SQL Code for the difference between two columns and altering a table

Tags: sql, difference

I have the following exercise given:
Determine `employee_Id`, name and salary of all employees. Add an intermediate column `new_salary` to the result that shows the current salary increased by 15%. The new salary must be returned as integer value.  And then add another intermediate column that shows the difference between the original salary and the new salary. The difference must also be returned as integer value.

What I have tried to code is the following:

```
select ID, name, salary,
       round (salary * 1.15, 0) as "new_salary"
from Employee;

alter table Employee
    add difference (salary, new_salary)
```

I think the first part (creating `new_salary`) is right, but I am not sure about the second part.

Comment: You're probably expected to _add another intermediate column that shows the difference between the original salary and the new salary_ to the SELECT, not to the base table.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: sql-server, postgresql, oracle...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is an exercise, it a kind of performing operations on existing data. There is no need of Altering the tables. Do not alter the tables until and unless it is really required to modify the structure of the table.

Please use below query for your solution,

```
select ID, name, salary,
       round (salary * 1.15, 0) as new_salary, (round (salary * 1.15, 0)) - salary as difference
from Employee;



select ID, name, salary,
       round (salary * 1.15, 0) as new_salary, (round ((salary * 1.15) - salary), 0) as difference
from Employee;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now I understand more how SQL Works! :) But now my problema is how to return the difference as interger. I have tried: select ID, name, salary,
       round (salary * 1.15, 0) as new_salary, (round (salary * 1.15, 0)) - salary as difference int
from Employee;

Comment: The result should be in integer only. Are you getting any decimals

Comment: Yes, like for example 398.00, just with ".00" but still not interger

Comment: Provided you the solution, please check

Comment: Hi! Now it gives me the following error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I think is something related with select cast(difference as INT) but I am not sure how to apply it

Comment: Hi! I tried the following and it worked:                                                                      select ID, name, salary,
       round (salary * 1.15,0) as new_salary, (round (salary * 1.15 - salary, 0)) as difference
from Employee;                                                                                                   Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: My pleasure. Can you make this answer as correct, so that others would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `select` statement, then that's simple arithmetics - the difference is just 15% of the original salary, so:

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    salary, 
    round(salary * 1.15, 0) new_salary, 
    round(salary * 0.15, 0) salary_diff
from employees
```

On the other hand, it you want to create new columns in the table itself, then I would recommend computed columns. The syntax may sligthly vary across databases, but the idea is:

```
alter table employee add new_salary  as (round(salary * 1.15, 0));
alter table employee add salary_diff as (round(salary * 0.15, 0));
```